# cURL PHP code redirect after success

Tags: php, curl

I created a Facebook login type code using cURL, and I was wondering how to redirect back to my website after a successful login to Facebook. Code is shown below:

```
<?PHP
    $login_email = '****';
    $login_pass = '****';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($login_email).'&  pass='.urlencode($login_pass).'&login=Login');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.facebook.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    $page = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));

    echo $page;
?>
```

Comment: that's not curl's job. `if (curl succeeds) { header('Location: ...'); }`

Comment: Why do you need to redirect? Your server is the one performing the login. The user never leaves your domain.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to use cURL to login to Facebook. Facebook provides [its own API.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0#authentication)

You can check if the `$session` variable in that API succeeds and then call the header method. Also see: [FaceBookRedirectLoginHelper](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/4.0.0)

And if you're looking to redirect, use `header()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```